# VBA Nested Do Until Loop With For Each Loop

Tags: vba, excel

The Do Until statement works perfectly; however, I cannot continue past the first worksheet. Thank you in advance for any help.

```
Option Explicit
  Sub InsertBlankRow()
    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

   For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
     rowCount = 2

        With ws

      Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(rowCount + 1, "D"))
         If (Cells(rowCount, "D") <> Cells(rowCount + 1, "D")) Then
            Range(Cells(rowCount + 1, "D"), Cells(rowCount + 2, "D")).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            rowCount = rowCount + 3
        Else
            rowCount = rowCount + 1
        End If
    Loop
    End With
Next ws
End Sub
```

Thank you all for the responses. Using the ws.Cells and ws.Rows caused the Do Until statement to not work. Once I removed ws. the rows were able to be added. It still will not loop through all the worksheets though.

Edited the code to provide what I am currently working with.

Comment: qualify  each `Cells` reference with `ws`. So `IsEmpty(ws.Cells(rowcount + 1, "D"))` and so on. Otherwise the code only looks at the ActiveSheet when the macro is run. Also read up on [avoiding Select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: Also `Rows..` so `ws.Rows(rowCount + 1).Select`

Answer (score 0):

You are increasing row count in first sheet and I am guessing your next sheet/s do not have more rows compare to first sheet. So move your **`rowCount`** inside **`For Each Loop`**, like this:

```
'rowCount = 2  'set to start row  'REMOVE FROM HERE

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    rowCount = 2  'set to start row
    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(rowCount + 1, "D"))
```

So on every sheet row will start from 2. Also incorporate all the changes suggested in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Following-up on Scott^2 (Holtzman and Craner), you need to reference all objects inside your `For Each` loop. I prefer using the `With ws` , it cleans and simplifies your code, all objects nested inside the `With` statement have `.` as a prefix (`.Cells(rowCount, "D")` and `.Rows(rowCount + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown`).

Also, there is no need to select the row before inserting 2 rows in between (always better to avoid using `Select` and `Selection`), you can directly use `.Rows(rowCount + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown`.

**Full "Clean" code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertBlankRow()

    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        rowCount = 2  'set to start row

        With ws
            Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(rowCount + 1, "D"))

                If .Cells(rowCount, "D") <> .Cells(rowCount + 1, "D") Then
                    .Rows(rowCount + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                    .Rows(rowCount + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                    rowCount = rowCount + 3
                Else
                    rowCount = rowCount + 1
                End If
            Loop
        End With
    Next ws

End Sub
```

**Extra**: if you want to insert 2 lines in between different values in column D with 1 code line, use the code line below :

```
.Range(.Cells(rowCount + 1, "D"), .Cells(rowCount + 2, "D")).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

Comment: Thank you all for the responses.

Comment: @ElisabethCurtis you're welcome, please mark as answer